# Can not open text files on desktop via doubleclick

Tags: gnome, 20.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 20.04. and thereby switched from Unity to Gnome (3.36.1). Now when I doubleclick on text files (`.txt` or files without any extension) on the desktop nothing happens. In `nautilus` everything works fine.

I've seen a lot of posts about `.desktop` files not working anymore on Gnome Desktop but non of them mention regular text files.

So is this another feature of Gnome or is there a bug?
I hope somebody can shed some light on this and/or know how to fix this, becaus it's really annoying.

PS: I've already installed `gnome-tweak-tool` and enabled desktop icons.

**UPDATE**

Turns out that the desktop implementation in nautilus is broken. The workaround is to install nemo and use its desktop instead.

For more details go to https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/nautilus/issues/158. The instructions for the workaround can be found under **Alternative solution**.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem. On each file that is on the desktop, I removed "allow running the file as a program" After that, it worked properly. Sorry for bad English.